# How to measure boot time of docker container

Tags: docker, containers, startup

I have a simple c based "Hello world" application that I dockerized into different base images. I want to measure boot time for the container. I tried running `time docker run my-app` but I am not sure if this is the correct way to get boot time. Any pointers will be helpful.

Application:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello world");
  return 0;
}
```

One of the Dockerfile:

```
FROM scratch
COPY hello /
CMD ["/hello"]
```

Comment: What is the exact time interval you're trying to measure?  Since this particular program doesn't do very much, `time docker run ...` will be fairly close to just measuring the Docker overhead; is this in the context of a more involved process?

Comment: I'm trying measure exact creation time of different namespace and objects.

Comment: you can see this [ref](https://serverfault.com/questions/897619/docker-startup-time/897634)